# SWIG-Lua question on class returning another class

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I am concreting a question I had earlier.

I have two classes in C++ and I use SWIG to wrap them. A method in one class can return a pointer to the other class. How can I get Lua to see it as more than just a userdata?

More concretely:

I have

```
class fruit
{
     int numberofseeds;
  //some other stuff about fruit constructors etc...
   public:
     getseedcount()
     {
        return numberofseeds;
     }
}

class tree
{
    fruit * apple; 
    public:
      //constructors and whatnot
    fruit * getfruit()
    {
         return apple;
    }

}
```

I wrap these two class with SWIG so I can access them in Lua

So I can get in Lua the object *x=pomona.tree(grannysmith)*.

My question now is: How can I arrange for things so that when I type *y=x:getfruit()* I will get a *pomona:fruit* type object? Where I can write something line *y:getseedcount()*?
At the moment all I get is userdata which not edible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SWIG .i file is set up correctly, you can use the ":" operator:

```
local y = x:getfruit()
local z = y:getseedcount()
```

See the "Classes" section (23.2.7) of the [SWIG Lua documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Lua.html#Lua_nn14).

If that doesn't work you need to tell SWIG how to convert a fruit* out parameter to a Lua representation using a typemap in your .i file.  Something like:

```
%typemap(out) fruit*
{
    swig_module_info* module = SWIG_GetModule(L);
    swig_type_info* typeInfo = SWIG_TypeQueryModule(module, module, "fruit *");

    SWIG_NewPointerObj(L, $1, typeInfo, 1);
}
```